# PHP page redirects using location: from url parameter

Tags: php, variables, location

I have a redirect PHP page which checks a URL Parameter and redirects to one of two pages depending on if the variable 'shore' is either 1 or not. My problem however, is that no matter what I do, the page is redirecting to the first option. Can anyone see anything obvious that I am missing?

Many thanks

```
<?php

  require_once('Connections/ships.php');

if ($_GET['shore'] = "1") {
   header( 'Location: shore_establishment.php?ship_id=' .urlencode($_GET['ship_id']) . "?shore=1");
   //echo"first";
} else if ($_GET['shore'] = "0") {
    header( 'Location: shipinfo.php?ship_id=' .urlencode($_GET['ship_id']). "?shore=0");
   //echo"second";
};

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like, @CommuSoft said, and your second `?` in your `$_GET` request should be an `&` instead.

Comment: Just to clarify do you mean the ? before shore=1

Comment: Yes, and any other parameters after that, that you wish to add.

Comment: @PHPglue: didn't noticed that :S. @user2406993: indeed, the HTTP standard specifies that URLs with a query should be written as `protocol://server/path/page.ext?arg1=val1&arg2=val2&arg3=val3`. Although I would agree the `&` makes life complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `==` instead of `=` to check the content of a variable

Furthermore I would advise you to use `else` instead of `else if` since there are only two options (this is more robust and in case in the end a third variable is introduced, the page would still do something).

Comment: thank you, I actually set it to if = 0 and if !=0 but i removed this to try and find my error.